# Remote desktop access to Ubuntu 14.04 behind an uncontrolled router

Tags: 14.04, networking, remote-desktop

The problem is I want to use the remote desktop to access to an Ubuntu 14.04 (A) from another Ubuntu 14.04 (B). A and B are not in the same network.

The machine A is behind a router and has a private IP address as 192.168.X.X. The router cannot be controlled, so the forwarding option does not work. But, I have a public IP address which can be accessed from outside.

Can anyone offer a solution on how to configure the network? Thanks!

Comment: can you enable dmz

Answer (score 1):

Since the router or firewall cannot be accessed to set up port forwarding to that host, the best recommendation I can give you is to set up a Reverse Tunnel to the host behind the firewall/router.

Information about setting up one can be found in the following link:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/11/reverse-ssh-tunnel/

I have not used the next one, but I have seen it recommended around.  It is TeamViewer.

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx